# Change UIFileSharingEnabled from code

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to change the `UIFileSharingEnabled` of my app programmatically ,the problem that it is set in the info plist and there is no way to change it programmatically.

i want to define it because i want only when the user want the UIFileSharingEnabled will work it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the **UIFileSharingEnabled** value programmatically.

Why do you think a user would not want to have it enabled? There are no disadvantages for him if it is on and he is not using it, are there?

Comment: I can think of at least of couple of scenarios when a user wouldn't want to enable file sharing.